# OpenAPI 3.0 Example Value Formatting Issues when UUID and Date-Time are Present

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

There seems to be an erroneous double quote that is messing with the example. If I set the example value by hand, it works fine. It only seems to be an issue with UUID's if there are multiple UUID fields in a single object or a mix of UUID and Date-Time formats.

When the Swagger default example value is displayed:
[image]

When the field is set with a sanitized example value:
[image]

Comment: What version of Swagger UI do you use? (Open the browser dev tools, swtch to the Console tab, and evaluate `versions`). [A similar issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6508) with syntax highlighting was fixed in v. 3.48. If you see this in the latest UI version, open an issue in the Swagger UI repository: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues

Comment: @Helen I am actually using the SwaggerHub IDE directly seeing this.

Comment: Send a bug report to [SwaggerHub support](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/message/).